# How to get details of Branch.io link from link_click_id

Tags: branch.io

App installed from Google Play store via a Branch.io link returns `referrer` as "link_click_id-123456"

How to get details of data associated with the link clicked by user from `link_click_id`?

Is it possible to debug details of `link_click_id` in Branch Arbor Debugging Tool?

Comment: How to get details of data associated with the link clicked by user from link_click_id? from application react native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here.

You can go to the following URL and get the details of your link data:
https://dashboard.branch.io/link-debug/[your_link_click_id]

Furthermore, you can monitor the stats of your link here:
https://dashboard.branch.io/link-stats/[your_link_click_id]

Hope this helps,

Jackie